# Adding Windows 10 UWA to existing UWP in store

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, store

I have an existing Window Universal Appliction on the store.
https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrdmn96
This app runs on Windows 10 as Windows 8.1 App.
I plan to release a "real Windows 10 UWA" for Windows 10 (Windows 10 Mobile) Users.
At the moment the app has three packages x86, x64 and ARM.

Can I add "dedicated" Windows 10 UWA to this App?
The app will have same functionality but a litte different look (due to new controls I'll use).

Idea: publish a new Version and additionally include the W10 UWA Packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add a UWP version of the app to your existing windows universal packages.  when you are done developing you can upload the UWP version with a higher version number than the universal app

Comment: Thank you Ken. Just to be sure I got you correct. I can (with a higher version number) publish ADDITIONALLY add a Win10 UWA to my app but keep the existing Win8.x Universal apps available (also with updated versions) at the same time?